# Is there a `shared_lock_guard` and if not, what would it look like?

Tags: c++, c++11, locking, c++14, mutex

I wanted to use a `std::mutex` in my class, and noticed that it isn't copyable. I'm at the bottom level of my library here, so it seems like a terrible idea to have this behaviour.

I used `std::lock_guard` on the `std::mutex`, but there doesn't seem to be a `shared_lock_guard`, which would be preferable to provide write-locks-exclusively behaviour. Is this an oversight or trivial to implement myself?

Comment: Maybe you need this: [std::shared_lock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_lock)

Comment: This sounds like a serious XY-problem/design flaw. I you have a mutex at class level, just leave it out from copying.

Comment: "*I'm at the bottom level of my library here, so it seems like a terrible idea to have this behavior.*" Mutexes generally shouldn't live "at the bottom level" of a library. At least, not in the way that you're suggesting. This sounds like you're trying to mutex-lock access to a utility class. That's generally a bad idea.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That is what I'll do. But the question about a `std::shared_lock_guard` to provide a scope guard for `std::shared_mutex::shared_lock` is still valid.

Comment: If you really want non-scoped locking (like, shared amongst multiple threads), enter the realm of `std::shared_ptr<std::lock_guard<Mutex>>` and all the fun associated with it, including memory leaks causing deadlocks. I'd personally prefer to see the X part of your XY-problem, hope we can help with that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With **`C++14`** You can use a [std::shared_lock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_lock) and a [std::unique_lock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock) to implement read/write locking:

```
class lockable
{
public:
    using mutex_type = std::shared_timed_mutex;
    using read_lock  = std::shared_lock<mutex_type>;
    using write_lock = std::unique_lock<mutex_type>;

private:
    mutable mutex_type mtx;

    int data = 0;

public:

    // returns a scoped lock that allows multiple
    // readers but excludes writers
    read_lock lock_for_reading() { return read_lock(mtx); }

    // returns a scoped lock that allows only
    // one writer and no one else
    write_lock lock_for_writing() { return write_lock(mtx); }

    int read_data() const { return data; }
    void write_data(int data) { this->data = data; }
};

int main()
{
    lockable obj;

    {
        // reading here
        auto lock = obj.lock_for_reading(); // scoped lock
        std::cout << obj.read_data() << '\n';
    }

    {
        // writing here
        auto lock = obj.lock_for_writing(); // scoped lock
        obj.write_data(7);
    }
}
```

**Note:** If you have **`C++17`**, then you can use `std::shared_mutex` for `mutex_type`.

Comment: I'm not so sure if the OP was asking for RW locks actually.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Maybe. But I can't think what else he means tbh.

Comment: Your solution is incorrect since it does not ever lock and unlock mutex. You need to wrap read_lock and write_lock into object with lock in constructor and unlock in destructor. Like it is done here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39186305/739731

Comment: @Sergey Both `read_lock` and `write_lock` are already such objects that lock the mutex in their constructor and unlock it in their destructor.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. You are right

Answer (score 2):

It’s not part of C++ standard yet, but you can find implementation example in boost.

```
template<typename SharedMutex>
class shared_lock_guard
{
private:
    SharedMutex& m;

public:
    typedef SharedMutex mutex_type;
    explicit shared_lock_guard(SharedMutex& m_):
        m(m_)
    {
        m.lock_shared();
    }
    shared_lock_guard(SharedMutex& m_,adopt_lock_t):
        m(m_)
    {}
    ~shared_lock_guard()
    {
        m.unlock_shared();
    }
};
```

It requires mutex class conforming to SharedMutex concept though;
 [std::shared_mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex) is part of proposed C++17 standard and boost had one already for some time: [boost::shared_mutex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_types.shared_mutex).