# Passing pointer to shared_ptr thread safety

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, shared-ptr, stdatomic

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <atomic>

struct Smth {};

struct B { //Used in thread 2
    B(std::shared_ptr<Smth>* smth) : smth_(smth) {};
    ~B();
    void DoSomething() {
        std::shared_ptr<Smth> newSmth = std::make_shared<Smth>();
        smth_->swap(newSmth);
    }
    std::shared_ptr<Smth>* smth_;
};

struct A { //Used in thread 1&3
  A() : smth_(std::make_shared<Smth>()), b_(&smth_) {};
  ~A();
  std::shared_ptr<Smth> smth_;
  B b_;
};
```

So is it good practice to pass pointer to shared_ptr so that i can swap the contents of shared_ptr in the separate thread?
The second question is should I use the std::atomic_store to replace the shared_ptr::swap, if so how should i do that?

Comment: *pointer to smart pointer* sounds like poor design. Yes, you'll need either atomics or locks to protect access to the shared resource, `smth_`.

Comment: consider the function `std::atomic_exchange` for `std::shared_ptr`, [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic)

Comment: @vu1p3n0x: `shared_ptr` is not trivially copyable, so you can't use `atomic<shared_ptr>`.  The ref-count block pointed-to by a `shared_ptr` instance has atomic counters, but the `shared_ptr` itself is not thread-safe.

Comment: @PeterCordes I wasn't referring to `atomic<shared_ptr>` but the atomic operations that can be called with `shared_ptr`s that I linked

Comment: @vu1p3n0x: thanks, I didn't realize those existed.  It's atomic but usually not lock-free: it's normally implemented with a mutex (using a hash table of mutexes, keyed by the pointer value).  Maybe m68k could be lock-free using its atomic memory-to-memory copy instruction, but most architectures don't have that.  Interestingly, C++20 is planning to deprecate it in favour of a `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr>` template specialization.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x: You can't *just* use `std::atomic_exchange`.  I think you have to change even the read-only accesses to use `atomic_load`, if they can happen at the same time as it's being mutated by `atomic_exchange`.  The wording in cppreference isn't 100% clear, but that's almost certainly what they mean.  You need `atomic_load` to respect the mutex that `atomic_exchange` takes while modifying the `shared_ptr` object.

Comment: Yes, the wording starting with _If multiple threads_ is unclear, but I believe it means the following (disjoint) cross-thread scenarios are safe (a) all accesses are to `const`-qualified member functions or (b) all accesses are via these `std::atomic...` overloads. I don't think they mean that you can use a combination of `const`-qualified access and these atomic overloads together, safely.

Answer (score 1):

My mind is boggling at how you might have ended up with this design choice... I hope it makes sense in your real project.

The *only* reason your should be passing a pointer (or preferably a reference) to a `shared_ptr` is to re-seat it (as you are doing) and you don't need to synchronize the *swap* itself (`shared_ptr` is already synchronized).

Swapping the contents, however, will cause synchronization issues with other threads that are using the object (reading or writing) at the time. So you would need to apply the same synchronization techniques you would apply if both threads were modifying the object.

This doesn't feel to me like a robust solution to whatever your actual problem is. Maybe consider passing a new `std::shared_ptr` to the other thread and then *signaling* it so it knows to pick up the new shared pointer (by copy not pointer).

Comment: Thread 2 is a periodic configuration retriever. Other threads use directly structure A. So you are suggesting that i implement in the structure B method getConfig that returns the copy of current shared_ptr directly to other threads on demand?

Comment: @user2207495 So other threads hold pointers to the same `struct A` object? Or do they each have their own `struct A` object containing *copies* of the original `shared_ptr`?

Comment: @user2207495 One thing to be aware of, reseating the `shared_ptr` will only reseat the *single* `shared_ptr` that you hold the reference to. All other copies of the original `shared_ptr` will remain unaffected and continue pointing to the original object.

Comment: @user2207495 My gut feeling (without really knowing your situation) is that you need to replace the pointed-to object using a (synchronized) *value copy* rather than manipulate the pointers. So every thread points to the same object using a (copied) `shared_ptr` and when it needs to change, you overwrite that object with a new copy (under synchronization).

Comment: Sorry for slow response, other threads hold pointers to the same struct A object. I need to store global configuration for other threads. When a new configuration appears in the periodic thread it automatically swaps the content so that every other thread will reload the configuration. Other threads are in read only mode so there should be no real race condition what so ever in my opinion.

Comment: @user2207495 So it seems you only have **one** `shared_ptr`? It sounds to me like maybe you just need a `unique_ptr`? In that case, what you are doing should work **but** you have to synchronize the swap because you do have a race condition. When the old object is destructed, other threads could be reading from it.

Comment: @user2207495 To be more efficient you can implement read/write locking (if you have `C++14` or later) along the lines of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39185420/is-there-a-shared-lock-guard-and-if-not-what-would-it-look-like/39185510#39185510

Comment: Well yes, I could use `unique_ptr` in this situation. But what do you think about this situation passing pointer to unique_ptr? Both for periodic thread and other threads?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162452/discussion-between-user2207495-and-galik).

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to (some) conventional wisdom, `shared_ptr` objects are themselves **not thread-safe**. That is, you cannot concurrently manipulate<sup>1</sup> a single `shared_ptr` object on different threads, any more than you could concurrently manipulate a `std::vector` or `std::string` or any other standard library object with "default" thread-safety.

The confusion arises because a typical `shared_ptr` does use atomic operations to manipulate its reference count - but that's only to support the scenario where *different* `shared_ptr` objects point to the same underlying object (and hence share a reference count).

This kind of hidden sharing is the same type of thing that used to occur with COW implementations of `std::string`: you could never safely manipulate the same `std::string` objects on different threads without locking, but the COW behavior meant that without atomic operations you couldn't even manipulate two *different* `std::string` objects which happened to share the same underlying buffer on different threads, a violation of the value-semantics of `std::string` objects and the standard library thread safety guarantees. So in practice, you had atomic operations to manipulate the COW buffer reference count, but the other operations were written as usual in a not-thread-safe way.

So the bottom line is that not only is probably a bad design to share a `shared_ptr` like this: it is explicitly not allowed since it is not thread-safe.

---

<sup>1</sup> Concurrently manipulate here means to access the `shared_ptr` objects on more than one thread, where at least some of the accesses are to non-`const` methods. The standard library provides a general guarantee that concurrent access that consists *only* of `const`-method access is safe (i.e., `const` serves as a flag that the operation is "read-only" from a threading perspective).

Comment: There are [some overloads of atomic functions for `std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic), as @vu1p3n0x mentioned.  They use a hidden mutex for you to make it possible to do stuff like atomically exchange what a `shared_ptr` points to, as long as all other accesses to that `shared_ptr` use `atomic_load` and so on.

Comment: @PeterCordes - thanks, I didn't even know those existed!