# Thread safety among classes with other classes for private variables

Tags: c++, multithreading, oop, class-design

I'm writing a game engine (for fun), and have a lot of threads running concurrently. I have a class which holds an instance of another class as a private variable, which in turn holds and instance of a different class as a private variable. My question is, which one of these classes should I strive to make thread safe?

Do I make all of them thread safe, and have each of them protect their data with a mutex, do I make just one of them thread safe, and assume that anybody using my code must understand that if you are using underlying classes they aren't inherently thread safe.

Example:

```
class A {
private:
     B b;
}

class B {
private:
    C c;
}

class C {
 // data
}
```

I understand I need every class's data to avoid being corrupted via a data race, however I would like to avoid throwing a ton of mutexes on every single method of every class. I'm not sure what the proper convention is.

Comment: It varies a lot depending on circumstances. This is a useful technique you can try. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39185420/is-there-a-shared-lock-guard-and-if-not-what-would-it-look-like/39185510#39185510

Comment: Thank you for your response @Galik, I will take this into consideration, I'm a little cautious about using C++17, I know many haven't adopted this standard yet.

Comment: It's probably not clear from the answer but the code is `C++14`. It is just the note at the bottom is for `C++17` users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost certainly don't want to try to make *every* class thread-safe, since doing so would end up being very inefficient (with lots of unnecessary locking and unlocking of mutexes for no benefit) and also prone to deadlocks (the more mutexes you have to lock at once, the more likely you are to have different threads locking sequences of mutexes in a different order, which is the entry condition for a deadlock and therefore your program freezing up on you).

What you want to do instead if figure out which data structures needs to be accessed by which thread(s).  When designing your data structures, you want to try to design them in such a way that the amount of data shared between threads is as minimal as possible -- if you can reduce it to zero, then you don't need to do any serialization at all!  (you probably won't manage that, but if you do a [CSP/message-passing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_sequential_processes) design you can get pretty close, in that the only mutexes you ever need to lock are the ones protecting your message-passing queues)

Keep in mind also that your mutexes are there not just to "protect the data" but also to allow a thread to make a series of changes appear to be atom from the viewpoint of the other threads that might access that data.  That is, if your thread #1 needs to make changes to objects A, B, and C, and all three of those objects each have their own mutex, which thread #1 locks before modifying the object and then unlocks afterwards, you can still have a race condition, because thread #2 might "see" the update half-completed (i.e. thread #2 might examine the objects after you've updated A but before you've updated B and C).  Therefore you usually need to push your mutexes up to a level where they cover all the objects you might need to change in one go -- in the ABC example case, that means you might want to have a single mutex that is used to serialize access to A, B, and C.

One way to approach it would be to start with just a single global mutex for your entire program -- anytime *any* thread needs to read or write *any* data structure that is accessible to other threads, that is the mutex it locks (and unlocks afterwards).  That design probably won't be very efficient (since threads might spend a lot of time waiting for the mutex), but it will definitely not suffer from deadlock problems.  Then once you have that working, you could look to see if that single mutex is actually a noticeable performance bottleneck for you -- if not, you're done, ship your program :)  OTOH if it is a bottleneck, you can then analyze which of your data structures are logically independent from each other, and split your global mutex into two mutexes -- one to serialize access to subset A of the data structures, and another one to serialize access to subset B.  (Note that the subsets don't need to be equal size -- subset B might contain just one particular data structure that is critical to performance)  Repeat as necessary until either you're happy with performance, or your program starts to get too complicated or buggy (in which case you might want to dial the mutex-granularity back again a bit in order to regain your sanity).