# Design of a holder class that will be used to store data at multiple places in the program

Tags: c++, mutex, smart-pointers

I am trying to design a class that works as a data holder (contains lot of members, getters and setters). This class shall be used at multiple other threads in the program and can be used for data exchange, i.e. one component updates the object and others can read out the changed values when needed.

Even if write of a member (by calling setter) can happen only at once place, however getter can be called at multiple places.

Below is the class code.

```cpp
#include <mutex>

class DataType{};

class DataStore
{
private:
    mutable std::mutex _mtx;
    DataType _member;
    // different other member!

public:
    DataStore(): _member(){}
    ~DataStore(){}

    // setters can be called from many places!
    void setMember(const DataType& val)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mtx);
        _member = val;
    }

    // getters can be called from many places!
    const DataType& getMember() const
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mtx);        
        return member;
    }
};
```

Questions:

- What is best way to create and share instance of this class, `singleton` or `const DataStore&` or `shared_ptr<DataStore>`?
- Do we need to make it thread-safe even if calling `setMember` happens only at once place? What are the possibilities to make it thread-safe? Will the existing code work?
- Some of the setters can be called very frequently, do I need to make the member as reference, `DataType& _member;`?

Comment: by locations/places do you mean threads? if yes then you will need to make it thread safe when setting and getting.

Comment: You can make that more efficient using *shared locking* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39185420/is-there-a-shared-lock-guard-and-if-not-what-would-it-look-like

Comment: Are you using this as a means of message passing between threads?

Comment: @B.D yes between threads, so this object in created in main thread and then passed to multiple threads in different classes. Do we need to make it thread safe even if set happened by one thread, get by multiple threads.

Comment: @soumyajit needs to have some synchronization even if its just a single thread that sets the data and multiple and reading. But if you can guarantee that the set and get operation do not occur at same time e.g. you set once at the beginning of the program then all the threads can get without synchronization .

Comment: @B.D how do you recommend I pass the object to other classes where threads r running? Someone can provide a sample code ?

Comment: @SoumyajitRoy if you are passing it to threads which are getting the data const reference seems to be good from what I have seen as it enforces the contract you are looking for. Whether to use a shared_ptr or singleton depends on the lifetime and ownership that depends on the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

> What is best way to create and share instance of this class, singleton or `const DataStore&` or `shared_ptr<DataStore>`?

Access to the class object is always read operation　when you choose singleton or shard_ptr.(I cannot understand what `const DataStore&` means.)

> Do we need to make it thread-safe even if calling setMember happens only at once place? What are the possibilities to make it thread-safe? Will the existing code work?

`getMember` returns const lvalue reference. So that your code doesn't lock anything. copy object or lock data access outside of this class.

You need to ensure that read operation and write operation doesn't occur at same time.

> Some of the setters can be called very frequently, do I need to make the member as reference, DataType& _member;?

As already pointed out, you should use `std::shared_mutex` outside of the class to avoid object copy. this means that you can simply remove the `DataStore` class because they are no longer needed.

Comment: 1. I need to share ths object with other class threads. So I can create and pass the object as shared_ptr or reference or pointer. Else I can have the class as singleton so any thread can access the object. Thats what I mean. 2. Also if I use shared_lock then the calling thread must get the lock on the whole object before seting or getting. right? 3. What do you mean in the last time? It would be great if u write a sample code. thanks.

Comment: Also can you explain the statement "to avoid object copy"?

Comment: " any thread can access the object." So that you can take mutex **outside** of singleton class. accessing shared_ptr, reference or ptr is read operation even if you do wrtite operation to the object pointed by shared_ptr, reference or ptr.

Comment: "Also if I use shared_lock then the calling thread must get the lock on the whole object before seting or getting. right?" shared_lock is not related. We always need to take the lock when read operation and write operation can be happened at same time.

Comment: "Also can you explain the statement "to avoid object copy"" when you define getter to copy object when create return value, instead of returning reference, taking the lock inside getter will give you thread-safe. How ever, object copy is not efficient. so you should avoid it. just take the lock outside of singletone class.